# Don't understand this "Not enough parameters for the SQL statement" error

Tags: python, mysql

```
# Import libraries
import os, re, subprocess, pyautogui, time, datetime, io
import mysql.connector
import csv


connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="xxxxx", password="xxxxxx", host="192.168.0.6", database="xxx"
)

cur = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

table = "inmuebles"

query = "SELECT * FROM %s;" % table

cur.execute(query)

with io.open("test.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=";")
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        writer.writerow(row)

connection.commit()
cur.close()
connection.close()


##############
### IMPORT ###
##############

connection = mysql.connector.connect(
    user="xxxxx", password="xxxxx", host="xxxxx", database="xxxx"
)

cur = connection.cursor(buffered=True)

sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM inmuebles_test"

try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        count = row[0]
        print("Initially there are %d rows in table" % (count))

except:
    print("Error: unable to fetch data")

cr = csv.reader(open("test.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8"), delimiter=";")
i = 1
next(cr)
for row in cr:
    print(row)
    print("inserting row-%d into Db" % (i))
    # cur.execute("INSERT INTO inmuebles_test VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",row)
    # connection.commit()
    i = i + 1
    if i > 10:
        break

try:
    cur.execute(sql)
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for row in results:
        count = row[0]
        print("Finally there are %d rows in table" % (count))

except:
    print("Error: unable to fetch data")

cur.close()
connection.close()
```

The code above exports to a csv file and then attempts to import it to the an identical table on a different server.

```
Not enough parameters for the SQL statement
```

This error occurs even when I import to a table with just two just two columns change line 70 to the following:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO inmuebles_test (id, referencia) VALUES ( %s, %s )",row)
```

If I comment out lines 70-71, then below is an example of a row which is printed out on like 68:

```
['6', '203-5938855', '203', '', '1', 'BLASCO IBAÑEZ', '15', '', '', '', '', '', '', '30027', '', '30', '30500', '1', '1', '1', '1970', '69.0', '0.0', '3', '1', '0', '1', '27718.0', '2018-09-05',
'35968.0', '2017-01-13', '27718.0', '2018-09-05', '', '0.0', '', 'El inmueble (PISO) se encuentra situado en el municipio de Molina de Segura (MURCIA). La vivienda está ubicada en un edificio de
un edificio de cuatro alturas. La vivienda se distribuye en tres dormitorios, salón-comedor, cocina, un cuarto de baño.', 'https://www.haya.es/vivienda-5938855/', '4', '2017-01-13', '38.060558',
'-1.215763', '', '0', '', 'TAU801688', 'Jennifer de Gea', 'BANKIA', 'G', '0.0', '', '1', '0.0', '2018-12-28 16:32:59', '2018-12-28 16:32:59', 'http://www.outletdeviviendas.com/estaticos/imagen.asp?f=685327_203-5938855_1.jpg&c=144']
```

Comment: Note that referencing line numbers of your posted code isn't terribly useful here (unless it's something obvious like "the third" or "second from last").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide same number of parameters to execute that are used in your query:

For e.g.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))
```

Also parameters should be either tuple or dictionary (not list) as mentioned here:

> This method executes the given database operation (query or command).
>   The parameters found in the tuple or dictionary params are bound to
>   the variables in the operation.

Source:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html

Comment: Thank you for your response. The following now works: 

cur.execute("INSERT INTO inmuebles_test (id, address) VALUES ( %s, %s )", ("hello", "hi")) 

However, this does not work:

cur.execute("INSERT INTO inmuebles_test (id, address) VALUES ( %s, %s )", (row[0], row[1]))

print(row) works but print(row[0]) does not...

Comment: I think `row` is not a list thats why `row[0]` is not working

Comment: Thanks for your help. The issue was that the csv file contained empty spaces between lines.